# Allocation-free enumeration and processing

Tags: c#, ref, stackalloc, stack-allocation

I would like to solve the massive allocation costs of a c# application.
The application itself can be represented by the `TickUser` class at the bottom, and I'd like to know how to implement the `TickStream` object and the `DoWork` and `ProcessTick` methods to use allocation-free data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Ticks {

    public interface ITick {
        double Price { get; }
        double Bid { get; }
        double Ask { get; }
        double Volume { get; }
        DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows allocation-free creation of an <see cref="ITick"/>, 
    /// but is inefficient to pass from method to method because it is large.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly struct Tick : ITick {
        public double Price { get; }
        public double Bid { get; }
        public double Ask { get; }
        public double Volume { get; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
        public Tick(double price, double bid, double ask, double volume, DateTime timeStamp) {
            Price = price;
            Bid = bid;
            Ask = ask;
            Volume = volume;
            TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Also allows allocation-free creation of an <see cref="ITick"/>,
    /// but this is efficient to pass from method to method because it is small,
    /// containing only a single pointer.
    /// It requires a <see cref="Tick"/> to be created once and guaranteed "pinned" to a location on the stack.
    /// </summary>
    public unsafe readonly struct TickPointer : ITick {

        readonly Tick* Ptr;

        public double Price => Ptr->Price;
        public double Bid => Ptr->Bid;
        public double Ask => Ptr->Ask;
        public double Volume => Ptr->Volume;
        public DateTime TimeStamp => Ptr->TimeStamp;

        public TickPointer(Tick* ptr) {
            Ptr = ptr;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the data stream.
    /// </summary>
    public class TickStream {

        /// <summary>
        /// Typically returns hundreds of millions of <see cref="ITick"/> values.
        /// To avoid massive allocation/deallocation costs, we want to yield objects that
        /// can only exist on the stack.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<ITick> GetTicks() {
            // How to implement??
        }
    }

    public class TickUser {

        public void DoWork() {
            var stream = new TickStream();
            foreach (var tick in stream.GetTicks()) {
                ProcessTick(tick);
            }
        }

        void ProcessTick(ITick tick) {

        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `TickStream` class, I'm ok with removing the `IEnumerable<Tick> GetTicks()` method and replacing it with the `MoveNext()` / `Current { get; }` / `Current()`pattern.

Perhaps `ref readonly TickPointer Current()`?

Comment: Boxing should be prevented ... I may need to get rid of the `ITick` interface?

Comment: You might want to look at `Span<T>` and ref structs

Comment: Yes, I just haven't been able to to figure out how to get there without compiler issues, hence the question here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out and performed tests with a number of alternate scenarios.
It turns out that creating the tick as a `ref readonly struct` gives best performance in all considerations if one is careful to always pass it around using the `in` parameter.

**Basic code**

```
using System;

namespace Ticks {

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows allocation-free creation of an <see cref="ITick"/>, but is inefficient to pass from method to method because it is large.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly ref struct Tick {
        public static Tick Empty => new Tick(0, 0, 0, 0, DateTime.MinValue);
        public bool IsEmpty => Price == 0;
        public double Price { get; }
        public double Bid { get; }
        public double Ask { get; }
        public double Volume { get; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
        public Tick(double price, double bid, double ask, double volume, DateTime timeStamp) {
            Price = price;
            Bid = bid;
            Ask = ask;
            Volume = volume;
            TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Also allows allocation-free creation of an <see cref="ITick"/>, but this is efficient to pass from method to method because it is small,
    /// containing only a single pointer.
    /// It requires a <see cref="Tick"/> to be created once and guaranteed "pinned" to a location on the stack.
    /// </summary>
    public unsafe readonly ref struct TickPointer {

        readonly Tick* Ptr;

        public bool IsEmpty => Ptr->IsEmpty;
        public double Price => Ptr->Price;
        public double Bid => Ptr->Bid;
        public double Ask => Ptr->Ask;
        public double Volume => Ptr->Volume;
        public DateTime TimeStamp => Ptr->TimeStamp;

        public TickPointer(Tick* ptr) {
            Ptr = ptr;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A reference-type implementation of the tick data for tests involving allocations.
    /// </summary>
    sealed class AllocatedTick {
        public readonly double Price;
        public readonly double Bid;
        public readonly double Ask;
        public readonly double Volume;
        public readonly DateTime TimeStamp;
        public AllocatedTick(double price, double bid, double ask, double volume, DateTime timeStamp) {
            Price = price;
            Bid = bid;
            Ask = ask;
            Volume = volume;
            TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Tick stream code**

```
sealed class TestTickStream {

    public readonly int NumTicks;

    readonly DateTime DummyTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    int count = 0;

    public TestTickStream(int numTicks) {
        NumTicks = numTicks;
    }

    public bool MoveNext(ref Tick tick) {
        if (++count > NumTicks) return false;
        tick = new Tick(count, count, count, count, DummyTime);
        return true;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A stream that returns <see cref="AllocatedTick"/> ticks for tests involving allocations
/// </summary>
sealed class AllocatedTickStream {

    public readonly int NumTicks;

    readonly DateTime DummyTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    int count = 0;

    public AllocatedTickStream(int numTicks) {
        NumTicks = numTicks;
    }

    public AllocatedTick MoveNext() {
        if (++count > NumTicks) return null;
        return new AllocatedTick(count, count, count, count, DummyTime);
    }
}
```

**Benchmarking code**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;
using Ticks;

namespace TIcks.Benchmarks {

    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class AllocationAndPassingBenchmarks {

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of ticks a stream should generate.
        /// </summary>
        [Params(1000, 100000, 10000000)]
        public int NumTicks { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The depth of methods that each tick should be processed through. To simulate methods calling methods.
        /// </summary>
        [Params(1, 10, 100)]
        public int MethodPassingDepth { get; set; }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TickPassedWithInParameter() {
            var stream = new TestTickStream(NumTicks);
            var tick = Tick.Empty;
            while (stream.MoveNext(ref tick)) {
                var x = Process(tick, 0);
            }

            Tick Process(in Tick tick, int depth) {
                return depth == MethodPassingDepth ? tick : Process(tick, depth + 1);
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TickPassedWithNothing() {
            var stream = new TestTickStream(NumTicks);
            var tick = Tick.Empty;
            while (stream.MoveNext(ref tick)) {
                var x = Process(tick, 0);
            }

            Tick Process(Tick tick, int depth) {
                return depth == MethodPassingDepth ? tick : Process(tick, depth + 1);
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public unsafe void TickPassedAsPointer() {
            var stream = new TestTickStream(NumTicks);
            var tick = Tick.Empty;
            while (stream.MoveNext(ref tick)) {
                var tickPointer = new TickPointer(&tick);
                var x = Process(tickPointer, 0);
            }

            TickPointer Process(TickPointer tickPointer, int depth) {
                return depth == MethodPassingDepth ? tickPointer : Process(tickPointer, depth + 1);
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void AllocatedTicks() {
            var stream = new AllocatedTickStream(NumTicks);
            for (var tick = stream.MoveNext(); tick is object; tick = stream.MoveNext()) {
                var x = Process(tick, 0);
            }

            AllocatedTick Process(AllocatedTick tick, int depth) {
                return depth == MethodPassingDepth ? tick : ProcessSlowTick(tick, depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class MemberAccessBenchmarks {

        [Params(100, 1000)]
        public int AccessCount { get; set; }

        [Benchmark]
        public void AccessTickMembers() {
            double price, bid, ask, volume;
            DateTime time;
            var tick = new Tick(1, 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now);
            for (var i = 0; i < AccessCount; i++) {
                price = tick.Price;
                bid = tick.Bid;
                ask = tick.Ask;
                volume = tick.Volume;
                time = tick.TimeStamp;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public unsafe void AccessTickPointerMembers() {
            double price, bid, ask, volume;
            DateTime time;
            var tick = new Tick(1, 1, 1, 1, DateTime.Now);
            var tickPointer = new TickPointer(&tick);
            for (var i = 0; i < AccessCount; i++) {
                price = tickPointer.Price;
                bid = tickPointer.Bid;
                ask = tickPointer.Ask;
                volume = tickPointer.Volume;
                time = tickPointer.TimeStamp;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var summary1 = BenchmarkRunner.Run<AllocationAndPassingBenchmarks>();
            var summary2 = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MemberAccessBenchmarks>();
        }
    }

}
```

**Member access results** (used to determine whether there accessing members via `TickPointer` is too slow, show that its best not to use the `TickPointer` idea unless absolutely necessary)

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-6820HK CPU 2.70GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.101
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.1 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.60701, CoreFX 4.700.19.60801), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.1 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.60701, CoreFX 4.700.19.60801), X64 RyuJIT
```

```
|                   Method | AccessCount |           Mean |        Error |       StdDev |     Gen 0 |     Gen 1 |     Gen 2 |     Allocated |
|------------------------- |------------ |---------------:|-------------:|-------------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|--------------:|
|    **AccessTickMembers** |     **100** |   **374.1 ns** |  **3.96 ns** |  **3.51 ns** |     **-** |     **-** |     **-** |         **-** |
| AccessTickPointerMembers |       100   |     412.0 ns   |    8.64 ns   |    8.88 ns   |         - |         - |         - |             - |
|    **AccessTickMembers** |    **1000** |   **728.5 ns** | **14.41 ns** | **17.70 ns** |     **-** |     **-** |     **-** |         **-** |
| AccessTickPointerMembers |      1000   |   1,013.0 ns   |   19.93 ns   |   22.95 ns   |         - |         - |         - |             - |
```

**Allocation and passing around results** (used to determine the best way to pass ticks from method to method as well as rapidly consume hundreds of millions of them from a stream without high allocations)

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-6820HK CPU 2.70GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.101
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.1 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.60701, CoreFX 4.700.19.60801), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.1 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.60701, CoreFX 4.700.19.60801), X64 RyuJIT
```

```
|                        Method |     NumTicks | MethodPassingDepth |                Mean |     Allocated |
|------------------------------ |------------- |------------------- |--------------------:|--------------:|
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** |     **1000** |              **1** |        **13.78 us** |      **32 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |       1000   |                1   |          17.80 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |       1000   |                1   |          12.81 us   |        32 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |       1000   |                1   |          15.59 us   |     56032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** |     **1000** |             **10** |        **17.64 us** |      **32 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |       1000   |               10   |          44.36 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |       1000   |               10   |          35.65 us   |        32 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |       1000   |               10   |          18.72 us   |     56032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** |     **1000** |            **100** |        **64.16 us** |      **32 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |       1000   |              100   |         368.49 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |       1000   |              100   |         257.56 us   |        32 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |       1000   |              100   |          72.04 us   |     56032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** |   **100000** |              **1** |     **1,349.07 us** |      **35 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |     100000   |                1   |       1,732.55 us   |        41 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |     100000   |                1   |       1,232.51 us   |        41 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |     100000   |                1   |       1,579.70 us   |   5600032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** |   **100000** |             **10** |     **1,705.52 us** |      **32 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |     100000   |               10   |       4,446.53 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |     100000   |               10   |       3,612.70 us   |        51 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |     100000   |               10   |       1,927.15 us   |   5600032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** |   **100000** |            **100** |     **6,190.00 us** |      **32 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |     100000   |              100   |      36,278.23 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |     100000   |              100   |      23,599.96 us   |        32 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |     100000   |              100   |       7,215.91 us   |   5600032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** | **10000000** |              **1** |   **133,903.50 us** |      **92 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |   10000000   |                1   |     174,813.80 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |   10000000   |                1   |     125,981.61 us   |       342 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |   10000000   |                1   |     142,317.59 us   | 560000032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** | **10000000** |             **10** |   **173,391.13 us** |    **2056 B** |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |   10000000   |               10   |     432,315.53 us   |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |   10000000   |               10   |     361,120.79 us   |        32 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |   10000000   |               10   |     192,561.14 us   | 560000032 B   |
| **TickPassedWithInParameter** | **10000000** |            **100** |   **615,150.00 us** |  **1368 B**   |
|     TickPassedWithNothing     |   10000000   |              100   |     3,792,146.58 us |        32 B   |
|       TickPassedAsPointer     |   10000000   |              100   |     2,520,775.19 us |        32 B   |
|            AllocatedTicks     |   10000000   |              100   |       685,623.22 us | 560000032 B   |
```

---

In summary, here is the best way I found to code the tick:

```
public readonly ref struct Tick {
    public double Price { get; }
    public double Bid { get; }
    public double Ask { get; }
    public double Volume { get; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
    public Tick(double price, double bid, double ask, double volume, DateTime timeStamp) {
        Price = price;
        Bid = bid;
        Ask = ask;
        Volume = volume;
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Here is the best way I found to code the stream:

```
sealed class TestTickStream {

    public readonly int NumTicks;

    readonly DateTime DummyTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    int count = 0;

    public TestTickStream(int numTicks) {
        NumTicks = numTicks;
    }

    public bool MoveNext(ref Tick tick) {
        if (++count > NumTicks) return false;
        tick = new Tick(count, count, count, count, DummyTime);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the best way that I found to consume the stream:

```
public void ProcessAllTicks() {
    var stream = new TestTickStream(NumTicks);
    var tick = new Tick();
    while (stream.MoveNext(ref tick)) {
        Process(tick);
    }

    void Process(in Tick tick) {
        // do semething
    }
}
```

If you can show some ways to improve this code, please share!